# Vue3 model updates initially after saving code, but not after a browser refresh

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have a bit of a quantum problem happening.  I have some code (below) that is not displaying the value of the data model.  So I put a `console.log` in to see what's going on and then it works... none of the other code changes, but by looking at it, it exists.  Then if I refresh the page, it's gone again

[Update] It's not the console.log itself (whew - that would be wierd).  It's the state when I change the file vs when i do a fresh browser load.  What's different there that I should be looking at?  I'm new to VueJS, and I'm really more of a python / backend dev anyway, so sorry if this is basic stuff.

The template code in child component

```js
              <v-text-field v-else
                @change="updateValue(field.name, $event)"
                persistent-placeholder
                :model-value="(item as any)[field.name]"
                :label="field.title || field.name"
              ></v-text-field>
```

item is passed in as a `Model` and converted as follows

```js
  props: {
    input: {
      type: Object || null,
      default: null
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      item: {...this.input},
    }
  },
```

which comes from the parent

```js
    <ModelComponentVue 
      :input="item"
    />
```

which gets the data in `created()`

```js
DataStore.query(User).then((items:Array<User>) => {
  if (items.length > 0) {
    this.item = items[0] // I suspect this could be not responding to reactivity in Vue3 ???
  }
})
```

Comment: The relevant info is missing, the parent data property declaration. Is the `item` property declared in parent or are you directly setting it without declaring it in parent's `data` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts of your code only use initialData contrary to what you might think. Pay attention to the code below.

```
  data() {
    return {
      item: {...this.input},
    }
  },
```

In the above code, you will only have the initial value of the input and you will lose the other values.
The easiest way to use props is to use them directly.

However, for more complex concepts, you can use computed or toRef, etc.

Try the code below

```
              <v-text-field v-else
                @change="updateValue(field.name, $event)"
                persistent-placeholder
                :model-value="input[field.name]"
                :label="field.title || field.name"
              ></v-text-field>
```

```
props: {
    input: {
      type: Object ,
      default: () => {}
    },
  },
```

Comment: this is pretty much the conclusion I also came up with.   The issue is that the input objects are read-only, so i need something that lets me change the values, so it becomes more complicated.   Componded by the fact that I was trying to over-generalise the view.  By making the view more specific, the problem went away.